# Color image classification and labeling algorithm

Tags: python, numpy

I have some code I've been using to de-noise some images and then label all unique and contiguous elements. The function `zoneMap()` de-noises the image by picking a random, unclassified point and then averages all points that are within a certain euclidean distance in color space. This repeats until each point has been classified. The function `labelPix()` handles the labeling by finding the unique elements in the image processed by `zoneMap()`, and then labelleing each individual contiguous region.

I am pleased with the output of the functions, however, I would really appreciate any advice on how they can be sped up.

```
import numpy, random, glob, os,
from skimage import io

def zoneMap(RGB, colorThreshold):

    [height, width, _] = RGB.shape
    mask = numpy.ones((height, width), dtype = bool)
    whiteValues = (RGB == 255).all(-1)
    mask[whiteValues] = False

    WHITEMASK = mask

    pix = RGB.astype(int)

    while True in mask:
        nextPossible = numpy.argwhere(mask == True)
        x, y = nextPossible[random.randint(0, len(nextPossible) - 1)]
        point = pix[x, y]

        distance = numpy.sqrt(numpy.sum((pix - point)**2, axis = -1))
        distance[numpy.invert(mask)] = 500
        toAverageCoords = (distance <= colorThreshold)
        mask[toAverageCoords] = False

        pointsToAverage = pix[toAverageCoords]
        average = pointsToAverage.mean(axis = 0)
        pix[toAverageCoords] = average

        unique, counts = numpy.unique(mask, return_counts=True)
        progress = dict(zip(unique, counts))
        print('Progress: ', (progress[False]/(height*width))*100, '%')

    return pix, WHITEMASK

def labelPix(pix):
    height, width, _ = pix.shape
    pixRows = numpy.reshape(pix, (height * width, 3))
    unique, counts = numpy.unique(pixRows, return_counts = True, axis = 0)

    unique = [list(elem) for elem in unique]
    del(unique[unique.index(list(pix[0,0]))])

    labeledPix = numpy.zeros((height, width), dtype = int)
    offset = 0
    for index, zoneArray in enumerate(unique):
        index += offset
        zone = list(zoneArray)
        zoneArea = (pix == zone).all(-1)
        elementsArray, numElements = scipy.ndimage.label(zoneArea)

        elementsArray[elementsArray!=0] += offset

        labeledPix[elementsArray!=0] = elementsArray[elementsArray!=0]

        offset += numElements

    return labeledPix

def main():
            file = PATH

            im = io.imread(file)
            pix = im[:,:,:3]

            mapArray, _ = zoneMap(pix, 25)

            labeledPix = labelPix(mapArray)

            toSave = NEWPATH

            io.imsave(toSave, mapArray)
```

I have been using this on images similar to the one linked, though any image should be suitable as input:

> [image]

Comment: One small thing to do that will speed up stuff is to use `dist = numpy.linalg.norm(a-b)` instead of `numpy.sqrt(numpy.sum((pix - point)**2)`

Comment: You should edit your title to a description of what your code does, not what you want out of a review. Your current title applies to basically all image processing questions on this site. You might also want to link to your [previous question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/184221/98493).

Comment: `threshold` is undefined.